# Is there a way to think about conditional vs unconditional heteroskedasticity graphically?

Tags: data-visualization, heteroscedasticity, conditional

I find I understand concepts much better with the aid of charts/visualizations. I'm struggling to intuitively understand how one would be able to see whether error terms are correlated or not to the independent variables.

Would this even show up on a chart?

Comment: Title refers to heteroskedasticity; contents refer to correlation between error terms and independent variables. Which is your concern?

Comment: @NickCox - thank you for the reply. Perhaps my language wasn't precise enough (or I have a misunderstanding) but my working definition of Conditional Heteroskedasticity is when the **variance** in error terms is correlated to the independent variables. Would you agree?

Comment: That makes a bit more sense but it still mixes distinct ideas. Unequal variance can exist together with zero correlation between error terms and predictors.

Comment: @NickCox - according to [AnalystPrep](https://analystprep.com/study-notes/cfa-level-2/quantitative-method/heteroskedasticity-serial-correlation/),  "Conditional heteroskedasticity occurs when the error variance is related/conditional on the values of the independent variables.".

So I guess what you are referring to, unequal variance with zero correlation, is what AnalystPrep calls "Unconditional heteroskedasticity".

So yes, this gets to the root of my question. How would these two types of heteroskedasticities be told apart on a chart?

Comment: Related to or conditional on is much more general than being correlated (having zero correlation). Otherwise, plot residuals versus fitted or versus predictors and start from there.

Comment: In my previous comment, zero correlation should be non-zero correlation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

These charts helped me in the past: variation(error term) at x grows (co-related) with x (independent variable).

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Am I correct that those charts show CONDITIONAL heteroskedasticity? What would unconditional heteroskedasticity look like on a chart?

Comment: When we say 'conditional', it has got to be 'conditional on one or some variables'. Look at the top left plot, if there is just x as our only independent variable, we are already observing heteroskedasticity without conditioning on anything, this is an unconditional heteroskedasticity. However, if you told me you indeed had a second variable (e.g. called age), and you draw that plot by choosing the part of data where age=20, then such heteroskedasticity is a conditional one, and is condition on age where age=20.